# How to Parse an Array of Strings (JSON) - iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, parsing

I have JSON that reads like this:

```
{
  "categories":["Love", "Hope, "Dreams"],
}
```

I am familiar with parsing arrays or dictionaries with objects, but I am slightly confused as to how to parse an array full of strings. How do I go about doing so?

Comment: NSArray *categories = [json valueForKey:@"categories"]; then NSString *love = categories[0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following custom method

```
-(NSArray *)stringArrayFromJsonFile:(NSString *)jsonFileName withKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *fileContents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsonFileName ofType:@"json"]];
    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fileContents options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSArray * stringArray = [dict objectForKey:key];

    return stringArray;
}
```

now call that method like

```
NSArray* stringArray =  [self stringArrayFromJsonFile:@"yourJsonFileName" withKey:@"categories"];
```

Comment: above code works when you want to get data from a json file which is in your app main bundle

Answer (score 2):

You should get the data first.

```
    NSString * JSONString = @"{\"somekey\":[\"somevalue\"]}";
    NSData * JSONData = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    id JSONResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    if ([JSONResult isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary * dictionary = JSONResult;
    } else {
        ...
    }
```